# How to pass data from an activity to a fragment on android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an activity named ‘Home’; I’m redirected to this activity after a login. This activity implements two fragments (Header & footer) in this way.

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);

mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

And I want to display mainly into the header fragment implemented into the 'Home' activity some data transferred from the logging activity. The problem that I’ve searched a little bit, I’ve found that we can just add or replace a fragment in the main activity and not in another fragment. I'm tried to fund a solutions but not yet. This is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String res) {
    //LoginTask = null;
    //showProgress(false);

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(res);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (jObj.getString("code").equals("1")) {

            infos = new Bundle();

            infos.putString("ID",jObj.getString("ID"));
            infos.putString("Name",jObj.getString("display_name"));
            infos.putString("ImgUrl","http://unchained-network.com/uploads/profilpics/53f5c570b6ac2.png");

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            HeaderFragement hf = new HeaderFragement();

            //Charger les infos dans l'activité
            hf.setArguments(infos);
            tr.add(R.id.frgmnt,hf);
            tr.commit();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
            //Lançer l'activité
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        } else {
            //password.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            //password.requestFocus();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error !");
            builder.setMessage("The information entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again!")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                 }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**And this is how i extract the data into the fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nameH);
    img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);

    Bundle infos = getArguments();
    name.setText(infos.getString("Name"));
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("ImgUrl")));

}
```

So any solution please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass data via intents? You have two activities `Login` and `Home`.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomesActivity.class);
                //Lançer l'activité
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In the above code, you could simply add an extra information like this

`myIntent.putExtra("name", "value");`

And then you could retrieve this in Home Activity

`String extra = i.getStringExtra("name");`

And then pass this extra to your header fragment.

Comment: The problem is my two fragments are independent, you say that I should pass data from home to fragment; I guess it’s the same thing if I want to pass it from login to the fragment directly. My fragements are implemented into the Home activity but they are separated.

Comment: What do you mean by separated?

Comment: I’ve created HeaderFragment (the class & the layout) and in the same way the footer, after I’ve implemented them into a navigation drawer, into a Home activity

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with your code to pass a variable to a Fragment. I've just copied your code and it works fine.

Activity:

```
Bundle infos = new Bundle();
infos.putString("ID", "1");
infos.putString("Name", "Gonzo");
FragmentMain frag = new FragmentMain();
frag.setArguments(infos);
```

Fragment:

```
Bundle infos = getArguments();
Log.i(getTag(), infos.getString("Name"));
```

I'd suggest you put some logging into the onPostExecute, or step through in debug mode. Ensure your json is returning what you expect it to.

As a general suggestion, infos.getString accepts two params, the second is a default value which may be useful. Also avoid using a hard coded key, like "Name" instead use a public static string and reference this.

Good luck.